# Finite Complements Topology and Convergent Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ together with $\mathcal{F}$, the finite complements topology.

I've been asked to determine two different sequences $(x_{n}), (y_{n})$ such that:

$1. \>(x_{n})\rightarrow p $ and $(x_{n})\rightarrow q$ where $p\neq q$ .

$2. \>(y_{n})$ doesn't converge to any point.

EDIT:

I've thought about defining a pairwise sequence to solve the first point, but I'm not sure about that so I still think help with both points.

Comment: Well, that's great that you've been asked to do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have plenty of examples in both cases :

1) a subset $U \subset \mathbb{N}$ is open if and only if it is the empty set or its complement $\mathbb{N}\backslash U$ is a finite set. Then **any** sequence $(x_n)_n$ of points of $\mathbb{N}$ having infinitely many distinct terms converges to **every** point $x \in \mathbb{N}$. To see this, take any open set $U$ containing $x$. Because $\mathbb{N} \backslash U$ has only a finite number of points, an infinite number of points of the sequence $(x_n)$ must be in $U$ and therefore there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for every $n \geq n_0$, $x_n \in U$. Thus, $(x_n) \longrightarrow x$.

2) Let $(x_n)_n$ be a **any** sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ such that there exist two values $l_1$ and $l_2$ which the sequence $(x_n)$ takes infinitely many times. Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be open sets containg $l_1$ and $l_2$ respectively. Then $\mathbb{N}\backslash U_1$ and $\mathbb{N}\backslash U_2$ are finite by definition. Assume that $x_n \rightarrow l$ for some $l \in  \mathbb{N}$. Let $V$ be an open neighborhood around $l$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(x_n) \in V$ for all $n \geq N.$ But this contradicts the fact that that $l_1$ and $l_2$ appear in the sequence infinitely many times. So the sequence $(x_n)_n$ has **no** limit in $\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So as far as I see I can choose $(x_{n})=n$ to get the first point (I thought it had to be 2 exact points that's why I got stuck) and $(x_{n})=1$ if n is odd and $(x_{n})=0$ if n is even to get the second point.

Comment: That's right, yes.